# Search for string and state whether present or not in new column

Tags: r, string, dummy-variable

I have a dataset with 63,000 rows in **R**. One of the columns contained a list of words in the format

```
("[\"Stunning seaside location\", \"24-hour emergency call system and secure video entry\", \"Mature landscaped gardens with large terraces and seating areas\", \"Walk out balconies to selected apartments\", \"Beautifully decorated homeownersâ\200\231 lounge\", \"Parking spaces and car ports are available via an annual permit\", \"Wheelchair access\", \"Lifts to all floors\", \"Fire detection\", \"Intruder alarm\"]", "[\"Village Location, 4 Bedrooms, Garden(s)\"]", "[\"Balcony\", \"On street/residents parking\", \"Central heating\", \"Double glazing\", \"Fireplace\", \"Rural/secluded\"])
```

They are property characteristics listed from sale websites.

I want to extract words from this column and create a new column that has a '0' or a '1' if the word is present or not to create a **dummy variable** for regression. Ideally, I would be able to group multiple property characteristics into one column, stating if they are present or not. I'm also aware that R may be sensitive to capitalisations and plurals so I want to be able to have multiple versions of words in one column. Ie I want to be able to put 'parking' 'Parking' 'parkings' 'Parkings' into the same column as they all represent the same feature but may be written differently in the text.

This is for a hedonic pricing method so I need as many property characteristic variables as possible.

Comment: Please share a reproducible example

Comment: check out string matching in **stringr**

Comment: This is a repeat of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72955579/search-for-and-extract-words-into-new-column/72956350#72956350.

Comment: @Chris flag as dupe then rather than answering.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search for and extract words into new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72955579/search-for-and-extract-words-into-new-column)

Answer (score -2):

In the (continued) absence of exact data I've taken the liberty to create my own toy data based on the OP's sample string:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Location = 1:3,
  Description = c('["Interesting seaside location", "24-hour emergency call system and secure video entry", "Mature landscaped gardens with large terraces and seating areas", "Walk out balconies to selected apartments", "Beautifully decorated homeownersâ\200\231 lounge", "Parking spaces and car ports are available via an annual permit", "Wheelchair access", "Lifts to all floors", "Fire detection", "Intruder alarm"]", "["Village Location, 4 Bedrooms, Garden(s)"]", "["On street/residents parking", "Central heating", "Double glazing", "Rural/secluded"]',
                  '["Stunning city location", "24-hour emergency call system and secure video entry", "Mature landscaped gardens", "Walk out balconies to selected apartments", "Beautifully decorated homeownersâ\200\231 lounge", "Parking spaces and car ports are available via an annual permit", "Lifts to all floors", "Fire detection", "Intruder alarm"]", "["Village Location, 4 Bedrooms, Garden(s)"]", "["Balcony", "On street/residents parking", "Central heating", "Double glazing", "Fireplaces", "Rural/secluded"]',
                  '["Nice off-shore location", "12-hour emergency call system", "Marine gardens with large terraces and seating areas", "Swimming pool", "Beautifully decorated homeownersâ\200\231 lounge", "Parkings and car ports are available via an annual permit", "Wheelchair access", "No Lifts", "Fire detection", "Intruder alarm"]", "["Village Location, 4 Bedrooms, Garden(s)"]", "["Balcony", "On street/residents parking", "Central heating", "Double glazing", "Fireplace", "Rural/secluded"]')
)
```

The OP merely says s/he wants to extract "words" from the location description; one example is given, namely "Parking" and its variant spellings. I assume that there will be more such `keywords`so I've assembled this list. Please feel free to delete or expand as needed:

```
keywords <- "(?i)Parking|Garage|Garden|Freehold|Fireplace|Balcon(y|ies)"
```

Note that `(?i)` is used to make the match case-insensitive.

Now if the aim is to count the occurrences of the `keywords` in the `Desciption`s, then this procedure works:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  # extract all occurrences of `keywords` into new column:
  mutate(keywords = str_extract_all(txt, keywords)) %>% 
  # unnest the listed items in the new column:
  unnest(where(is.list), keep_empty = FALSE) %>% 
  # prepare `keywords` for `pivot_wider` below:
  mutate(
    # capitalize initial letter:
    headings = sub("^(.)", "\\U\\1", keywords, perl = TRUE),
    # standardize "Balconies" to "Balcony":
    headings = sub("Balconies", "Balcony", headings)) %>%
  # cast each `heading` into its own column and count its occurrences:
  pivot_wider(names_from = headings, values_from = headings, 
              values_fn = function(x) 1, values_fill = 0)
# A tibble: 21 × 7
   Location Description                                                                            keywords Garden Balcony Parking Fireplace
      <int> <chr>                                                                                  <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
 1        1 "[\"Interesting seaside location\", \"24-hour emergency call system and secure video … garden        1       0       0         0
 2        1 "[\"Interesting seaside location\", \"24-hour emergency call system and secure video … balconi…      0       1       0         0
 3        1 "[\"Interesting seaside location\", \"24-hour emergency call system and secure video … Parking       0       0       1         0
 4        1 "[\"Interesting seaside location\", \"24-hour emergency call system and secure video … Garden        1       0       0         0
 5        1 "[\"Interesting seaside location\", \"24-hour emergency call system and secure video … Balcony       0       1       0         0
 6        1 "[\"Interesting seaside location\", \"24-hour emergency call system and secure video … parking       0       0       1         0
 7        1 "[\"Interesting seaside location\", \"24-hour emergency call system and secure video … Firepla…      0       0       0         1
 8        2 "[\"Stunning city location\", \"24-hour emergency call system and secure video entry\… garden        1       0       0         0
 9        2 "[\"Stunning city location\", \"24-hour emergency call system and secure video entry\… balconi…      0       1       0         0
10        2 "[\"Stunning city location\", \"24-hour emergency call system and secure video entry\… Parking       0       0       1         0
# … with 11 more rows
```